# The name httpWebRequest.ContentType doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I do not get this error when I use the below code for a new request in a method but when I try to use it in class level, I do get this error. The code is simply as follows;

```
 HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("EndPointUrl");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

I get the error for the second line of this code when I use it in class level.

Comment: Can you show more context? You can't do that at the class level but that is not the error you would get if that were the problem.

Comment: I am actually trying to understand why I cannot use it at the class level. It works in a method and I get the access token from the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

ContentType is a Header value, not part of the request. Try

```
httpWebRequest.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue( "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: But it works when I use it in a method and I get a response and access token from the API endpoint. I tried your code but I get the same error at the class level.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [A class can contain declarations of the following members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/class).

> Constructors, Constants, Fields, Finalizers, Methods, Properties, Indexers, Operators, Events, Delegates, Classes, Interfaces, Structs, Enumerations

`httpWebRequest` is a field and fields are allowed to be initialized at the class level.

`httpWebRequest.ContentType` is not a field, it is a variable assignment which is not allowed at the class level.

If you understand why you cannot take the code out of a method and paste it at the class level, then that is the same reason.